# Cannot import AD module in powershell: Error initializing default drive: 'Alocal error has occurred'

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have Powershell (2.0) and I am doing some scripting with ActiveDirectory cdmlets. I am on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

I was using the module, and after some time, I suddenly cant import the module(see screenshot), nor create a New-PSDrive with the AD Service:

[image: When loading module]

[image]

Again, I am running this inside the server, and i have admin credentials - it was working some 30 minutes ago. Can someone help me out on how to solve this?

Also, this happened to me yesterday, but after some minutes it worked again, so it is intermittent.

EDIY: Using the -verbose flag, it loads "everything", but after the 4th import, it gives the warning/error. Not sure if it loaded it:
[image]

Comment: Run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Verbose` and see if it reveals anything useful

Comment: @JamesQMurphy See my edit, i added a picture.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no.  Did you see [this over on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/203123/unable-able-to-run-remote-powershell-using-active-directory)?

Comment: Yes, but its not exactly my case: I am running the cmdlets inside the server.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Its happening again!!